# .htaccess in subfolder doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm hosting my site on Godaddy server.
On the server I have 5 sites, each site on individual folder.
for example: "webroot/site1"
I directed specific domain to the specific folder on the server "/site1"

The problem:
I tried to make a RewriteRule with .htaccess in the subfolder but it keeps telling me 404 not found.

This is the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

this works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

this redirect to 404 page:

```
#rewirite categories only
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/.*$ /category.php?c_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

this url works perfect:

```
www.example.com/category.php?id=1
```

this url doesn't work and redirect to 404 page

```
www.example.com/category/1/blalba
```

More details:

1. The other 4 folders are word press sites.
2. In the webroot there is another wordpress site.
3. In the webroot there is an empty htaccess file.
   I already tried to do
4. I already tried to do:

   RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/.*$ /site1/category.php?c_id=$1 [L,QSA]

**EDIT:**

I don't have category folder is just for the URL I want that it will redirect me to category.php with the id parameter

This is the error I get:

Not Found

The requested URL /site1/category/1/area-rugs was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: What is location of above `.htaccess` and what is DOCUMENT_ROOT of `site1.com`?

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` will need to be in the htaccess file in the root folder of the website.

E.g. if the directory structure is something like this:

```
/webroot/site1.com/
/webroot/site1.com/.htaccess
/webroot/site1.com/index.php
/webroot/site1.com/category.php
```

I'd have this code in the `.htaccess` file in `site1.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [R=301]

# Handle categories
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) /category.php?c_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I don't need or have category folder. I want to use this RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) /category.php?c_id=$1 [L,QSA] but it doesn't work and redirect me to 404 page. is there any way to understand the problem?

Comment: I don't have something like this: /webroot/site1.com/category/ I have something like this: /webroot/site1.com/category.php

Comment: @llioor OK, I've simplified my answer based on your comments - does it work?

Comment: @llioor Could you mark this question as answered if I've answered it correctly? Or provide your own answer if you've solved it yourself?